# How to load dataset from String in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

From spark's [document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.3/ml-classification-regression.html), I know I can load from a `libsvm-formatted` dataset from file.

However, I want to run codes in a remote spark cluster, so I hard coded the iris dataset into my code, and I want to directly load from this String object.

However, when looking into the [DataFrameReader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html) object, I find there is no API which supports direct loading dataset from `String`.

Comment: Hi @calvin, can you please check my answer, if it works for you, please upvote + accept :)

Comment: Hi @SomeshwarKale, your answer partially solves my question, however, I actually want to load a `libsvm-formatted` dataset rather than a `csv-formatted` dataset

Comment: Hi @calvin, if you have filesystem enabled, you can create temporary file from string libsvm and load the same file as dataframe-val df = spark.read.format("libsvm")
     .option("numFeatures", "780")
     .load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")

Comment: @SomeshwarKale So there is no direct API to do this, I need to use some workarounds, get it, thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this way-

```scala
 val irisData =                                                                                           
   """                                                                                                    
     |"sepal_length","sepal_width","petal_length","petal_width","label"                                   
     |5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa                                                                         
     |4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa                                                                         
     |4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa                                                                         
     |4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa                                                                         
   """.stripMargin                                                                                        

 println(irisData)                                                                                        

   "sepal_length","sepal_width","petal_length","petal_width","label"                                      
   5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa                                                                            
   4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa                                                                            
   4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa                                                                            
   4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa                                                                            

val stringDS = spark.createDataset(irisData.split("\n"))(Encoders.STRING)                           
 val irisDatasetDF = spark.read                                                                           
   .option("inferSchema", "true")                                                                         
   .option("header", "true")                                                                              
   .csv(stringDS)                                                                                         
 irisDatasetDF.show(false)                                                                                

   +------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+                                        
   |sepal_length|sepal_width|petal_length|petal_width|label      |                                        
   +------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+                                        
   |5.1         |3.5        |1.4         |0.2        |Iris-setosa|                                        
   |4.9         |3.0        |1.4         |0.2        |Iris-setosa|                                        
   |4.7         |3.2        |1.3         |0.2        |Iris-setosa|                                        
   |4.6         |3.1        |1.5         |0.2        |Iris-setosa|                                        
   +------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```